# MySQL database not loading table data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, centos, centos-7

My centOS 7 server had an unexpected shutdown. For some reason one of the mysql database shows that all tables are empty, but if I browse the files in /var/lib/mysq/database I can see the files(.frm and .ibd and the other files) opening them with a text editor I can read some of the data in it.

What's wrong here? why is one of my database not reading the files or loading the data?

Edit: I still have all my files related to the database such as ibdata1, all other databases/schemas are working fine except for one. That one database I can browse the tables but loading the data shows empty tables.

Comment: Look at the log files.  They may tell you that it crashed in a bad way and point you at a web page that explains how to "recover" the data.  Do not try to edit any files.

Answer (score 0):

First attend to the error for which the server had **unexpected shutdown**. Without attending this you can not move ahead.

And then for the database / tables missing data...

**1. Log files are to start with.**

Find the date/time range in which those particular .frm and .ibd files and the ibdata1 are last updated (not last accessed) and look for all entries of all **relevant** log files. Hope you can check all **relevant...**

Once the lines of log files with issues are identified, you yourself can correct them **or else just post them here**

**2. Look at**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html